# Specify 'lenient: true' in your resource generation options to ignore unsupported columns

Tags: solr, cassandra

I am trying to create solr core for the following cassandra table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1(
    id      UUID,   
    nm          TEXT,
    crtime_t    TIME,       --creation time in nanoseconds
    issys       BOOLEAN,
    conttyp     TEXT,

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I am using the following command to create the solr core :

> dsetool create_core graph.table1 generateResources=true

But it seems time field is not supported by solr as it is producing the following error:

> org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException:
>   Type org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeType is not supported with
>   automatic Solr schema generation. Specify 'lenient: true' in your
>   resource generation options to ignore unsupported columns.

I am fine with ignoring unsupported columns (in my case: crtime_t), but how should I specify lenient as true in resource generation options? And what does it mean by lenient : true? I tried:

```
dsetool create_core graph.table1 generateResources=true & lenient=true
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a .yaml file with 'lenient: true' in it and then use the option coreOptions='path.to.yaml.file' to generate it.